# Recently swapped domains - New site isn't being indexed, old domain currently 301 Redirect to new

Tags: seo, google-search-console

So I'm a little stumped on exactly what has happened here.

We were previously on a https:// domain that is still appearing in Google search engine but I've indicated to the webmaster tool that this is now being redirected.

I've used a site:https:// search. Old site still comes up, new one doesn't.

The new site is set up and it works. Property is added correctly in the Google webmaster search console.

Its been about 4 days now, and none of my pages have been indexed. Google Search console indicates there are no problems.

How long does this generally take? I've never had to do this before.

Does Google have a problem with this kind of behavior?

I've never experienced something like this and I'm not sure what I can do to resolve.

Comment: A 302 direct is probably not what you want. You want 301. As well, it takes far more than 4 days for anything to happen. It all depends upon how popular, trendy, and fresh your site is. Most sites can take months for all of the pages to be fetched. Fix the redirect and be patient. It will work out.

Comment: @closetnoc Sorry, I am performing a 301, mistype 302. I'll just give it a bit more time. I'm normally deploying brand new sites/domains which tend to be instant on indexing. This one is just being difficult!

Comment: You may need to put the old site verification Id in tags in the new pages? To prove the new site "agrees" it is the new site?